# Parameters of AMDeviceInstallApplication function()

Tags: iphone, xcode

Can anyone tell me the parameters of `AMDeviceInstallApplication function()` in `iTunesMobileDevice.dll`?

Answer (score 1):

```
AMDeviceInstallApplication(IntPtr sockInstallProxy, IntPtr cfStrPath, IntPtr opts, CallBack callback, IntPtr unknow);
```